# What is the difference in usage between 夜【よ】 and 夜【よる】？

Tags: usage, readings

As I understand, both よ and よる mean 'night'. I guess that the difference might be purely idiomatic. In this sense:

- What are idioms where only one of them is correct?
- What are idioms where you can use either?
- If you can use either, is there a difference in nuance?

Comment: As usual, explanations of downvotes are appreciated.

Comment: I'm just a little interested in the etymology of る in words like よる and ひる.

Comment: 「よる」より「よ」の方が、ちょっと昔っぽい感じするよね。「秋の[夜]{よる}は・・・」より「秋の[夜]{よ}は・・・」の方が文語的っていうか。

Comment: @Chocolate 分かりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4):

Both readings are kun-readings of kanji 夜 and are used in native Japanese words.

I think the main difference is that:

- 夜{よる} is rather used as a standalone word meaning evening or night.
- 夜{よ} is used in compound words, e.g. 夜{よ}中{なか} (midnight), 闇{やみ}夜{よ} (dark night), 夜{よ}空{ぞら} (night sky).